# Pronunciation of bath and maths in British English

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

In Southern standard British English, *bath* is pronounced as /bɑːθ/ with a long *a* while *maths* is pronounced as /mæθs/ with a short *ae* sound. Why does that happen?

Both *maths* and *bath* end with θ. Even though both of them start with bilabial sounds they are pronounced differently. Is there any rule for that?

Comment: Even in AE the sound changes when you add the S.

Comment: No rule that I know of as a southern BrE speaker. Don't forget though, that  **maths** is an abbreviation of **mathematics**.

Comment: Also the word [**hath**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hath) (still used in sayings) is pronounced with a short **a** sound, but [**aftermath**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/aftermath) with a long **a**.

Comment: @WeatherVane - You're kidding, eh?

Comment: @HotLicks about what, exactly?

Comment: @WeatherVane - You said "aftermath" has a long "a".  Lexico codes a long "a" as "eɪ".

Comment: @HotLicks the lady in this [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqLzg7bNucg) (which claims to pronounce British English) speaks "aftermath" with a short 'a' in both syllables. I say it with a long 'a' in both syllables.

Comment: @WeatherVane - How do you pronounce "hay"?

Comment: @HotLicks, I speak the way I speak, just as you do. Please don't pull the "where the heck did you learn English anyway" thing on me, because I learned it in England.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Please don't say "X is pronounced Y" just because that's how you pronounce it.

Comment: @WeatherVane - that bespectacled woman is from Greenock (Scotland) according to the accompanying text. She says 'aftermath' with short As and rhotic Rs, just like one would expect a Scots person to.

Comment: Weather Vane, are you really asserting that anyone says 'arftermarth'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey it's a well enough known pronunciation for [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/aftermath) to have it as its final audio clip. Another comment disputing me overlooked that.

Answer (score 3):

The pronunciation of *ath* as /ɑːθ/ in certain British accents applies mainly to monosyllabic words. (There's also /ɑːðə(r)/ in the disyllables *lather, rather.*) Polysyllabic words like *pathogen, Catherine, cathode* have /æ/. Although *maths* is one syllable, it is short for the polysyllabic word *mathematics* /ˌmæθəˈmætɪks/, and so is pronounced with the same vowel sound in the first syllable.

Similarly, according to the Oxford English Dictionary, *staph* which is short for *staphylococcus* is pronounced only as /stæf/, unlike *staff* which can be pronounced as /stɑːf/.

So I would say the general rule is that /æ/ does not change to /ɑː/ in words that are short forms of longer words with /æ/. There is at least one word that could be considered an exception: *graph,* which the OED says was "Originally an abbreviation of graphic formula", and which can be pronounced as /grɑːf/. But I think that in modern times, people don't think of *graph* as short for anything, so I would argue that it is not a genuine exception.